# How to make it so that players can only see one specific player but not the others?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unity-networking

I'm developing an educational game whose main mechanics are not multiplayer-oriented. However, I would like to add a feature that allows the teacher to enter the game and all students can see him, but no student can see the other students.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you know the ID of your teacher (even easier if you make them the master in a p2p game), then it should be easy to turn their avatar/model/character's renderer on and just not turn on the other players. I think if you have questions like this though, you definitely need to look into the architecture of networked games more though...

Answer (score -1):

If one object (teacher) could be seen by others (students) - it is multiplayer game.

If you want to students couldn't see each other - this is details of realization of multiplayer game.

Therefore, yes, there is a way to do that:

Packets about teacher send to all students. Packets about students send only to teacher, but not to another students.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it gave some guidance about how to control which packets get sent to whom in a Unity multiplayer game.